# I want to print the value in sales

Tags: c#

I want to print the value of the amount of sales entered by user times .10. My first issue is I want to store a value that a user enters into sales then times that by .10 then print the value of sales. We I run the program I get two lines one is the amount of sales entered the other is .5.

```
        const double COMMRATE = 0.10;

        string inputstring;
        double sales =5;
        char response;
        Console.Write("Do you want to Calculate Sales A or B or E...");
        inputstring = Console.ReadLine();
        response = Convert.ToChar(inputstring);
        while (response == 'A') 
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Sales", sales.ToString("C"));
            sales = sales * COMMRATE;
            inputstring = Console.ReadLine();
            response = Convert.ToChar(inputstring);
        }
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the value of inputstring inside the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .5 is coming about because you've set the default value of sales to be 5, and 5 * 0.1 = 0.5.

But why is that happening? Let's take apart your loop:

1. It asks the user to enter an amount of sales.  The second parameter is ignored, because "Enter Sales" has no format string placeholders. It does not perform line-reading of any form.
2. Without asking for input, it multiplies Sales by the commission rate and stores that to Sales.
3. Now it asks for user input,
4. which it immediately spits back out exactly as written (the amount-of-sales-entered line.)

What you actually need to be doing is a second Console.ReadLine() to get a string for the amount of sales, then use Double.ParseDouble() to get the entered amount of sales. Multiply that by your COMMRATE and print that back out- then give your "Do you want to Calculate..." question again, and then use the response from that to decide whether or not to continue the loop- currently, response is never getting modified, so you've created an infinite loop.

Unfortunately, you aren't even really close to the right code here. Your loop should look more like

```
while (response == 'A'){
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Sales");
    string salesStr = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(Double.Parse(salesStr) * COMMRATE);
    Console.WriteLine("Enter A to continue, anything else to quit");
    response = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

...which should get you started towards making your program do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you intend?

```
    const double COMMRATE = 0.10;

    string inputstring;
    double sales;
    char response;
    Console.Write("Do you want to Calculate Sales A or B or E...");
    inputstring = Console.ReadLine();
    response = Convert.ToChar(inputstring);
    while (response == 'A') 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Sales");
        inputstring = Console.ReadLine();
        sales = Double.Parse(inputstring);
        Console.WriteLine("Sales = " & sales);
        Console.WriteLine("Commission = " & sales * COMMRATE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time discerning what exactly you're asking.

If you want to print the value multiplied by the COMMRATE then you should probably put the calculation above the write statement.

```
sales = sales * COMMRATE;
Console.WriteLine("Enter Sales", sales.ToString("C"));
```

Although since you said you want to STORE the value entered by the user and THEN print it times the COMMRATE maybe you should use something like

```
double calculatedSales = sales * COMMRATE
Console.WriteLine("Enter Sales", calculatedSales.ToString("C"));
```

so that you're not redefining the original sales amount